# How to view things in a given plane in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I haven't found a way to see things that I plot with `plot3` inside a particular plane. For example, I would like to see the projection of all my objects inside a 2-D view, corresponding to the plane `x+y+z=1`. Is there any command to do that?

Comment: Do you actually want to project the points into the plane, then plot them, or just plot them and view the plot from a given plane?

Comment: @Wolfie plot them and view the plot from a given plane

Comment: @Wolfie Actually the projection in itself is okay. It is purely a question of visualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `view` command, passing in the normal vector to your plane:

```
view([1,1,1])
```

In this case (as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524246/why-are-the-coefficients-of-the-equation-of-a-plane-the-normal-vector-of-a-plane)) we can take the normal vector from the coefficients `[a,b,c]` of the equation

```
ax + by + cz = d
```

Example when plotting the plane itself:

```
[x y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1);
z = 1 - x - y;
surf(x,y,z)

view([1,1,1]); % <-- key line

xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

[image: plot]

Moreover, we can plot the normal line which will be invisible from this view as you are looking directly along it!

```
hold on
plot3( [0 1], [0 1], [-1 1], 'r' )
```